# Gmail filter undisclosed recipients

Tags: email, filter, gmail

I'm trying to filter out emails from a specific user that BCC's everyone for group emails. I'd like to receive any emails that they sent directly to me, but the group emails are as good as junk. How can I filter for undisclosed recipients to keep these group emails in a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://ask.metafilter.com/220192/How-do-I-filter-out-emails-with-an-empty-To-fields-in-Gmail), you can try using the following filter:

```
deliveredto:myemail@gmail.com AND -to:myemail@gmail.com AND -cc:myemail@gmail.com
```

Even simpler, the following seems to work:

```
from:(sender@email.com) to:(-me)
```